# converting a dataframe from float64 to object using dtype

Tags: python, dataframe

I have written this function long time but when i tried it now im getting an error message

```
def saveToDisk(i):
    print("saving ***")
    name='kenos'+str(i)+'.csv'
    d = {'adId':adId, 'Title':title,'Price':prices,'Description':description, 'Location':location,'Ddate Posted':datePosted, 'Location':location, 'Features' : features, 'URL':urlToSave, 'Type' : listingType}
    df = pd.concat([pd.Series(v, name=k) for k, v in d.items()], axis=1 )
    df.to_csv(name,index=False)
    resetAll()
```

and i get this error message

```
"df = pd.concat([pd.Series(v, name=k) for k, v in d.items()], axis=1 )
DeprecationWarning: The default dtype for empty Series will be 'object' instead of 'float64' in a future version. Specify a dtype explicitly to silence this warning."
```

im not really sure how to resolve this issue, i appreciate if i could get any help. thanks

Comment: thst's not a error it's warning

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem myself.

As the error warning suggests, for empty series the default will be `object` rather than `float64`. To remove the warning specify the default data type when instantiating the Series in your code.

Try this code:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.Series(v, name=k, dtype = 'object') for k, v in d.items()], axis=1)
```

Documentation at this link: [What’s new in 1.0.0 (January 29, 2020)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.0.0.html)